# can you run a network through another network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking

So I have a spare router(that shall henceforth be known as router1) and I wanted to know if I could connect router1 to my home wifi. Connect my phone to router1 and have it such that when my phone requests packets for a webpage from router1 it then requests that same information from my home wifi and thus my phone gets internet and my home wifi doesn't see past router1 so it can't tell if it's my phone connected.

Comment: Welcome to [su]! Yes, this is possible. In fact, that's exactly how your home router talks to the internet, via your ISP's network. router1 would need to be configured to look for your home router. But, how to do it depends on whether you want router1 to connect to the home router over WIFI or over an ethernet cable. The latter is easier. I would 1) save your settings for router1, 2) Reset it to factory defaults, and 3) research all the set-up options, to see which one most closely matches what you want, 4) Restore your router1 settings if you get frustrated with it. :-)

Comment: What are you trying to hide from?  Your phone likely generates unique traffic that can easily be sniffed to detect it is a phone, even if it's hidden behind a router.

Comment: Two parts of your question are not clear to me. Do you want to connect router1 to your home wifi via wifi or a wired connection? Most routers cannot connect as a wifi client - only an access point, so you'd probably need a wired connect. Second, can you clarify "so it can't tell if it's my phone connected"? If you mean others on the home wifi network can't see the phone's mac address when your phone is connected to router1, then you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  You may have some issues with "[double NAT](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3175739/how-to-identify-and-resolve-double-nat-problems.html)" and you definitely must/want to use different subnets that do not have any address overlap.